# Intel EFI shell on Mac

Tags: efi

I would like to try Intel's EFI shell.

How can I (build and) install EFI Shell on Mac? I've seen prebuilt binary, but I'd like do build it myself and I don't trust stuff from file-sharing sites.

There is EDK but isn't it for Windows only or maybe I can built it on OSX somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still looking for an answer I found one on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777437/sopen-s-firmware-console-on-mac-osx-intel

It does not seem possible to do this.

The only thing you can install to get some kind of EFI boot menu options menu is rEFIt, which can be found here:

http://refit.sourceforge.net

I know it isn't the answer you were probably looking for but I hope that this answer at least helps you out.